# How do I sort an array of arrays containing two values in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, sorting

My code for the Array of objects:

```
NSNumber* myNumber = [f numberFromString:num];

NSMutableArray *tempArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[tempArr addObject:startTime];
[tempArr addObject:myNumber];
[_timeSheets addObject:tempArr];
```

To access the value of myNumber, I use the following code:     NSNumber *temp2 = [[_timeSheets objectAtIndex:1] objectAtIndex:1];

I am displaying timeSheets, a mutable array, on a tableView.  When the user clicks on a button, I want to reorder and display timeSheets using the smallest myNumber value to the biggest myNumber.
How can I sort the array by using just one value contained in an array of arrays?

Comment: If the array only has two values, it might be simpler to insert them in the right order and be done with it

Comment: the amount of arrays in the array is dependant on how many values the user inputs

Comment: @grasGendarme The array being sorted has an arbitrary number of two-element sub-arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSArray` and `NSMutableArray` offer a number of sorting methods. For your purpose, the easy way would probably be to use `-sortUsingComparator:` like this:

```
[_timeSheets sortUsingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {
    if ([obj1 objectAtIndex:1] > [obj2 objectAtIndex:1]) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    }
    if ([obj1 objectAtIndex:1] < [obj2 objectAtIndex:1]) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
}];
```

The block you supply gets two parameters and returns a `NSComparisonResult`. Each item in your array is itself an array, so the objects you'll get for `obj1` and `obj2` are your two-element sub-arrays. The comparison block is applied repeatedly to pairs of objects in the `_timeSheets` to determine their relative positions.

*Note:* The comparator block above is based on the example in the [`NSArray` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html). Look there for more information on sorting.

Comment: just learning objective c, but wouldnt that only sort thru 2 of the objects in my array?

Comment: @objectivelyC No. The block compares only two items in the array being sorted, but it's called many times to compare different pairs of items.

Comment: If the #s 111, 222, 444, 333, 555 are entered in order, they re-order to 333 444 111 222 555... why does this happen?

Comment: I added integerValue to the end of the compare statements and now it works, thank you @Caleb